# How to merge two csv files using multiprocessing with python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge two CSV files with a common column using python pandas. With a 32 bit processor, after 2 gb memory, it will throw memory error. How can I do the same with multi processing or any other methods?

```
import gc
import pandas as pd
csv1_chunk = pd.read_csv('/home/subin/Desktop/a.txt',dtype=str, iterator=True, chunksize=1000)
csv1 = pd.concat(csv1_chunk, axis=1, ignore_index=True)
csv2_chunk = pd.read_csv('/home/subin/Desktop/b.txt',dtype=str, iterator=True, chunksize=1000)
csv2 = pd.concat(csv2_chunk, axis=1, ignore_index=True)
new_df = csv1[csv1["PROFILE_MSISDN"].isin(csv2["L_MSISDN"])]
new_df.to_csv("/home/subin/Desktop/apyb.txt", index=False)
gc.collect()
```

Comment: memory error as my understanding in 32 bit cpu only handle upto 2 gb for one process after that they will throw memory error

Comment: Try [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/) first. If that fails use a real database or Spark.